# Java backward compatibility doesn't work

Tags: java, gradle

I've created library for encoding/decoding property files. Library has two main purposes:

1. Encode property file and save it to another file.
2. Return key value from encoded file (decode file, store result as string in memory, load string to Properties object and return result from properties object).

Everything seems to work fine but today I've noticed that library doesn't work on java 1.5. I've noticed that problem occurs on decoding side so let's focus on this code. Assume that code responsible for decoding looks like that:

```
String props = "key1=val1\nkey2=val2";
Properties p = new Properties();
p.load(new StringReader(props));
p.list(System.out);
```

After few tests I saw that the problem is with this line:

```
p.load(new StringReader(props));
```

I found that Properties class in java 1.5 doesn't have `load(Reader)` declaration. To meet java 1.5 API requirements I changed this line to `load(InputStream)`. Everyting works fine now but here is the question.

I use gradle to compile project and I knew that this library should work on java 1.5+ ( I've java 1.7 installed on my computer) so I added to build.gradle those two lines

```
sourceCompatibility = '1.5'
targetCompatibility = '1.5'
```

I thought that java compiler will know that I want to compile code with compatibility to java 1.5 and will show appropriate errors. To be sure that it isn't gradle problem I compiled java code from command line but with the same result (compiler doesn't show any errors). So why compiler doesn't show any errors while compiling?

Java 1.5 Properties class API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

Java 1.6 Properties class API: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html

**[UPDATE]**

Neither `-source` or `-target` will check API compatibility. If so how can I check it in gradle? **As millimoose wrote maven has this plugin (http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/index.html) but what with gradle?**

Comment: Neither `-source` nor `-target` check whether you use API methods not present on the given JDK version. There's a Maven plugin that does though: http://mojo.codehaus.org/animal-sniffer-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: Ok, but how to prevent this? Do I need to use different jdk version during compilation?

Comment: Either use that Maven plugin, or a different JDK, yes.

Comment: Thanks, I use gradle so I'll try to find suitable plugin for it. BTW what is the sense of using `-source` and `-target`?

Comment: Target: Because each new JDK version introduces a new bytecode version. Old JVMs can't run code in a new format. Source: Because occasionally new language features are introduced, and the new language features won't work on an old JVM. The source option prevents you from using newer language features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the sections of the javac documents named "cross-compiling" and "Cross-Compilation Example".

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#crosscomp-options

Specifically this part:

> It is important to use -bootclasspath and -extdirs when
>   cross-compiling; see Cross-Compilation Example below ....... If you do not
>   specify the correct version of bootstrap classes, the compiler will
>   use the old language rules (in this example, it will use version 1.6
>   of the Java programming language) combined with the new bootstrap
>   classes, which can result in class files that do not work on the older
>   platform (in this case, Java SE 6) because reference to non-existent
>   methods can get included.

Comment: +1: This is an excellent find, I wasn't even aware / forgot those things exist

Answer (score 2):

The `-source` switch only instructs the compiler to give a compilation error if you use a language construct not supported in the specified version. For example using try-with-resources with `-source 1.6` will result in a compilation error, as it is only supported in Java 7 and higher. Its use is more a sanity check (ie: is my code still compatible with Java version 1.x)

The `-target` switch instructs the compiler to emit byte code compatible with the specified version. That is: the compiled code can run on the virtual machines of the specified version.

However neither of these switches make the compiler check for compatibility with Java libraries of an earlier Java version. That is why since Java 7, the compiler gives a warning if you use `-target 1.6` (or earlier), that you should also specify the `-bootclasspath` to point to a Java runtime library set of that java version so that it can check if your code is only using classes and methods of that Java version.